# Esper 6.1.0 out of memory

Tags: esper

1. Iam using Esper to get the count of vehicles from a traffic stream for 1 min running window,
2. It is working fine, iam able to get the count based on the grouping of sensor, vehicle type and direction.
3. It runs for a day but at the end of the day it gives out of memory, can you please help us resolving this.
   4.I have used @Hint to reclaim, please suggest if the EPL has to be changed

Info:
a) Esper version : 6.1.0, not the Enterprise Edition
b) JDK: 1.8
c) OS: RHEL 7.0
d) EPL:

```
@Hint('reclaim_group_aged=60,reclaim_group_freq=5')
select max(time) as time, event_name, object_class, object_id, 
    world_position, provider, tenant, speed, count(time) as vehicle_count, 
    sum(speed) as avg_speed, sensityScope as scope_id, sensityLane as lane,
    suportedBearing as bearing, objectType as object_type,
    pomLatitude as pom_latitude, pomLongitude as pom_longitude,
    refSpeed as ref_speed, sid, geoPoint, roadClass 
from com.cisco.cdp.traffic.esper.event.SensityTrafficEntity#time(1 minute)
group by sensityScope, object_class, event_name, suportedBearing
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is how time advances in your application. Time is controlled by your app. Therefore when time stops moving forward the 1-minute window doesn't remove events anymore.

The @hint is unnecessary by the way as empty groups go away since there is a time window.

I have tried reproducing this but don't see memory increasing. Here is the code I tried and that works fine. You could use my code as a template to test your specific query.

Also make sure that none of the fields of the event are mutable.

```
public class TestABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.getEngineDefaults().getThreading().setInternalTimerEnabled(false);
        EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(config);
        epService.getEPAdministrator().getConfiguration().addEventType(SomeEvent.class);
        epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(0));
        String epl = "@Hint('reclaim_group_aged=60,reclaim_group_freq=5') select sum(valueOne), valueTwo, key from SomeEvent#time(1 minute) group by key";
        EPStatement stmt = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(epl);
        SupportUpdateListener listener = new SupportUpdateListener();
        stmt.addListener(listener);

        long time = 0;
        while(true) {
            epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(time));
            time += 1000;
            epService.getEPRuntime().sendEvent(new SomeEvent(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), 0, 0));
            System.out.println("At time " + time);
            listener.reset();
        }
    }

    public static class SomeEvent {
        private final String key;
        private final int valueOne;
        private final int valueTwo;

        public SomeEvent(String key, int valueOne, int valueTwo) {
            this.key = key;
            this.valueOne = valueOne;
            this.valueTwo = valueTwo;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public int getValueOne() {
            return valueOne;
        }

        public int getValueTwo() {
            return valueTwo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fields "sensityScope, object_class, event_name, suportedBearing" all require well-defined hashcode and equals.